# Terraform with docker provider , can't pull the image

Tags: docker, terraform

My Terraform config.tf:

```
 provider "docker" {
   host = "tcp://my_dockerhost:2376/"
 }


resource "docker_container" "ubuntu" {
  name = "foo"
  image = "${docker_image.ubuntu.latest}"
}


resource "docker_image" "ubuntu" {
  name = "ubuntu:precise"
}
```

Error on apply:

```
 docker_image.ubuntu: Creating...
 latest: "" => "<computed>"
 name:   "" => "ubuntu:precise"
 Error applying plan:

 1 error(s) occurred:

 docker_image.ubuntu: **Unable to read Docker image into resource: Unable to find or pull image ubuntu:precise**
```

I tried deleting all the existing local images from my system and then ran it again. I also checked with `docker images` and I noted that it does pull the image, but I'm still unable to succeed with the apply command and results in the same error.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Most possibility is your docker setting issue. Can you check if docker daemon running and if you can telnet the port 2376? Secondly, run latest terraform with it.

Answer (score 2):

Used your exact config and it was successful for me. See output below:

```
docker_image.ubuntu: Refreshing state... (ID: sha256:5b117edd0b767986092e9f721ba23649...f53f1f41aff9dd1861c2d4feubuntu:precise)
docker_container.ubuntu: Refreshing state... (ID: 0482ec57dadff257a64815b10ac1d97863844a16852af7326046bb2ce3c8de0a)
aws_key_pair.mykey: Refreshing state... (ID: mykey)
aws_instance.example: Refreshing state... (ID: i-054b71ec0f9fe55bb)
docker_image.ubuntu: Creating...
  latest: "" => "<computed>"
  name:   "" => "ubuntu:precise"
docker_image.ubuntu: Creation complete (ID: sha256:5b117edd0b767986092e9f721ba23649...f53f1f41aff9dd1861c2d4feubuntu:precise)
docker_container.ubuntu: Creating...
  bridge:           "" => "<computed>"
  gateway:          "" => "<computed>"
  image:            "" => "sha256:5b117edd0b767986092e9f721ba2364951b0a271f53f1f41aff9dd1861c2d4fe"
  ip_address:       "" => "<computed>"
  ip_prefix_length: "" => "<computed>"
  log_driver:       "" => "json-file"
  must_run:         "" => "true"
  name:             "" => "foo"
  restart:          "" => "no"
docker_container.ubuntu: Creation complete (ID: a069e59359f19902d75642c584746c70098ed4f76f04d4570ae53f2383774649)

Apply complete! Resources: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

The state of your infrastructure has been saved to the path
below. This state is required to modify and destroy your
infrastructure, so keep it safe. To inspect the complete state
use the `terraform show` command.

State path:
```

Answer (score 1):

In the image resource, use the full name of the Docker image repository.

For example, adding "docker.io":

```
resource "docker_image" "ubuntu" {
    name = "docker.io/ubuntu:precise"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I didn't have enough space locally. After cleaning up to get some space, it was able to pull the image.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).